# How to use data client-side on static pages generated by Nuxt.js?

Tags: nuxt.js, server-side-rendering, static-site-generation

I'm building a website with Nuxt.js 2 with static site generation.

I receive the data in my asyncData function and use it to generate the page. That works fine.

I'd like to use that same data afterwards, when the page is loaded in the browser but the object is undefined - I thought it would be working.

As a concrete example: I have a recipe page in which I'd like to adapt the quantities of each ingredient based on a number of servings, which can be incremented/decremented client side.

```
data () {
        return {
            recipe: null,
            servings: 0
        }
    }
,

async asyncData({ params, error, payload, $axios, $config: { graphqlEndpoint } }){
        console.log("payload",payload);
        console.log("params",params)
        if (payload){
            let recipe = payload;
            recipe.compositions.sort((a,b) => b.quantity - a.quantity);
            return { recipe: recipe };
        }
        else {
            if(params.id){
                console.log("fetchRecipe", params.id);
                const res = await $axios({
                        url: graphqlEndpoint,
                        method: "post",
                        data: {
                        query: queries.getRecipeDetails(params.id),
                        },
                    })
                if(res.data.data && res.data.data.recettes[0]){
                    let recipe = res.data.data && res.data.data.recettes[0];
                    recipe.compositions.sort((a,b) => b.quantity - a.quantity);
                    return { recipe: recipe, servings:recipe.yield};
                }
                else{
                    error({ statusCode: 404, message: 'Page not found' })
                }
            }

            error({ statusCode: 404, message: 'Page not found' })
        }
    },
computed:
    {
        servingsRatio(){
            //this.recipe here doesn't exist on the client -> error
        return this.servings / this.recipe.yield;
        }
    }
```

How could I keep / hydrate the data to be able to use it client-side ?

You can see the page here: https://fristouille.netlify.app/recette/nouilles-sautees-au-tofu-et-chou-vert/6194/

Comment: You are not supposed to have `recipe` in `data` again, please remove it since `asyncData` is already returning + creating that state for you. You only need to have it already defined when using the `fetch()` lifecycle hook.

Comment: Hi Kissu, indeed, you're right ! :) Any idea why I can't use `recipe` in JS once the page is rendered statically ?...

Comment: You should be able to do so. Something is probably wrong. No errors in the console, nothing useful in the Vue devtools?

Comment: It works fine when I'm in dev mode (with `npm run dev`) and I don't get any error, 

however once I'm on the statically generated page (`npm run generate`) I get the error `this.recipe is undefined` on the browser console :(

Comment: Please update your snippet with my first comment feedback. Let's fix all of the issues before debugging further.

Comment: Hi kissu ! I've done it and even corrected an error (I wasn't returning the same object when I had no payload). But the problem persist. I'm surely missing something...

I'm thinking about rewriting the page from scratch.

Source code of the page is here: https://github.com/nbwns/fristouille/blob/master/pages/Recette/_slug/_id.vue 

Maybe your eyes will see something mine don't... Thanks a lot !

Comment: Probably a private repo since I do have a 404.

Comment: Gosh, I'm so stupid ! https://gist.github.com/nbwns/d53eae2ba173f79e7b3de3d40251a0a8